# Sharing memcache with php and nodejs

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, memcached

Is it possible to share javascript objects/php associative arrays with memcache?

Or should I convert the data into a string when sharing them?

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON data fromat to share data between this languages (PHP and JavaScript).

```
//read from memcache in JS (node.js)
var data = JSON.parse(from_memcache);
//or before write
data = JSON.stringify(data);

//read from memcache in php
$data = json_decode($data_from_memcache);
//or before write
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Ok, so I should just save simple strings?

Comment: Yes, strings and try save smallest possible volume of data. Save only variable data (e.g. don't save html in memory (memcache)).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and the best way to do this is to encode your objects to the JSON format.
Memcache is nothing more than a key => value storage, which means everything you store in it is a string (of bytes).